# How to point a domain registered with ENS to swarm content?

Tags: ropsten, swarm, hosting, ens, resolver

I'm hosting my web site [on swarm now](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/f1a669a425b378bd8034fe0df7fea098c8b932a6037b688764afda1e92a8db1e/index.htm). And I registered a `.test` FIFS domain to point to it: `5.test`

I can verify that I am the owner of that domain with the `ensutils.js`:

```
> ens.owner(namehash('5.test'));
"0xdcf407eae88d480e280db2d0deaa3a11c82eaa9b"
```

I use the public resolver:

```
> ens.setResolver(namehash('5.test'), publicResolver.address, {from: eth.accounts[0]});
"0x2800127128657a5f9483fe4062364456fddbee5ba98b4cd3071c60fb466bb267"
```

And finally, I tell it there is swarm content at the hash location:

```
> publicResolver.setContent(namehash('5.test'), 'f1a669a425b378bd8034fe0df7fea098c8b932a6037b688764afda1e92a8db1e', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000})
"0x957ae9864fc56505f3e19af3b3d85c7c1317ad53628533170599423501c07d8f"
```

As far as I can tell, all the transactions executed correctly. However, navigating to [bzz:/5.test/index.htm](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/5.test/index.htm) does give me:

```
Manifest not Found
```

Any idea? How to correctly use the ENS registered domains with swarm hosted content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add '0x' to the beginning of the content hash in the setContent function.

```
publicResolver.setContent(namehash('5.test'), '0xf1a669a425b378bd8034fe0df7fea098c8b932a6037b688764afda1e92a8db1e', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000})
```